# Why am I exploding during lightning storms?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Every so often during lightning storms I see what looks like static shooting of of me for a few seconds and then I explode and die.  What is happening and how can I prevent it?

[image: Electric static on Link]

A few seconds later you will end up with a screen filled with light:

[image: Lightning explosion]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason you are exploding is because metal weapons and armor attract electricity in a lightning storm.  Wearing an item that has the electrical discharge effect (such as the weapons in the figure below) will cause charge to build up until you explode.  Un-equip those items and you won't build up charge.

[image: Metal Weapons with static charge]

Comment: You can usually get away with one metal item equipped.

Comment: @JeffMercado I once picked up a metal item in a storm which equipped automatically, and was promptly struck by lightning before I could switch it. So I wouldn't risk it...

Comment: @Kat: I need to rephrase, you can get pretty far with a single metal item equipped and never get struck, but you're not completely safe. Just odds of getting struck is significantly better the less you have.