# How effective of a lightning rod can you be?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

So, as we know, equipping yourself with a metal weapon, shield or bow can cause you to attract lightning during a storm. This can be either painful, or hilarious, depending on whether or not you have the lightning helm.

But, my question is does wearing more metal equipment increase the frequency, or decrease the timer for attracting lightning strikes, and can wearing metal armour affect this as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are in the middle of a thunderstorm, **anything** metallic will turn you into a lightning rod as long as you have it equipped. Based on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302287/124566), you can see which items will attract the lightning by looking at them in the menu.

Wearing metallic gear does not change the frequency, but it does increase the changes of being struck by lightning. Every 5 minutes in game (which is 5 seconds outside of game), the lightning will find a target to strike. The more metallic gear you are wearing, the greater the chances are being the target.

If you start to spark, you will have 10 seconds to switch out your gear or warp to a safe location.

---

Source

- [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/632936-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75081165) (lightning frequency)
- [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/632936-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75147325) (in-game vs out-game seconds)
- Personal experience

Comment: If the quests have not been completed yet, a good place to personally test this are the [Trial of Thunder](https://www.polygon.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-guide-walkthrough/2017/3/19/14975342/trial-of-thunder-shrine-quest-toh-yahsa-shrine-rubber-armor-location) and [A Song of Storms](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/A_Song_of_Storms) shrines. These have constant thunderstorms until the shrines are completed

Answer (score 0):

It does for me, as I used to have a metal shield equipped most of the time and never got shocked, but once I got a full suit of armor I got zapped instantly after equipping it

Comment: Does that happen consistently? Otherwise it seems that's probably just chance, and unrelated.

Comment: Yep, I just went back through and waited for a storm. Then I put on my soldier's armor set and every time it zapped me within 5 seconds or so. Though I did get zapped once with just the shield, I think that it's probably a scale depending on how many items you have equipped are metal